# How can one use chrome-extensions in/on unsupported webpages?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, chrome-web-store, unsupportedoperation

I was wondering how I could use chrome-extensions on unsupported websites like chrome://extensions or on chromiums/chromes new-tab website, or any other unsupported website.

**I tried to use a chrome-extension universally.**

I searched in *chrome://flags*, searched *chrome://settings* and the (on Linux) local .config-folder for chromium as well as stackoverflow and chromiums documentation but **did not find a proper solution or anything helpful**, please help me and thanks in advance!

> (In my case the extension in question is called crxMouse Chrome Gestures, if someone wants to look it up/use it - link is here:)
>  [Chrome extension in question](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crxmouse-chrome-gestures/jlgkpaicikihijadgifklkbpdajbkhjo)

Comment: You can add the key for google's screen reader extension to your manifest.json, but that'll work only in your personal unpacked extension: `"key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDEGBi/oD7Yl/Y16w3+gee/95/EUpRZ2U6c+8orV5ei+3CRsBsoXI/DPGBauZ3rWQ47aQnfoG00sXigFdJA2NhNK9OgmRA2evnsRRbjYm2BG1twpaLsgQPPus3PyczbDCvhFu8k24wzFyEtxLrfxAGBseBPb9QrCz7B4k2QgxD/CwIDAQAB",`